# How to make a "typedef" involving a nested class?

Tags: c#, typedef, using, nested-class

I can do

```
using MyType = System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeClass.AClass>;
```

Now i only need MyType to be used within SomeClass. So i dont really need SomeClass to be public. However i can only do this outside of my namespace.

So how do i work this in such a way i can use MyType without making SomeClass and SomeClass.AClass public?

Comment: it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is

Comment: @BrokenGlass: tl;dr version. I cant do that with private classes! How do i use it with private classes?

Comment: Why do you need a `using` at all if MyType is only used within SomeClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what this could gain you apart from saving keystrokes. If you want to do this to keep the option of easily replacing the `List` with another type of collection, then you can change the static types of the variable holding the collection to an appropriate interface.

That said, if you *must* go this way for some reason, there is always this option:

```
// Just to be used as a typedef
class MyType : System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeClass.AClass>
{
}
```

You can do this inside `SomeClass`.